# C code to create a linked list segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Ok, so for my homework I have a function that creates a linked list from file input and it's like a calendar, so it  reads in a date and title from a file. I'm using a head node that is globally declared to make it
easier to work with other functions.
This is my node struct:

```
typedef struct event_t{  
    char title[20];  
    event_date_t date;  
    struct event_t *next;  
}event_t;
```

event_date_t is just a simple struct for the date
Here's the function:

```
void insert_events_linked_list(FILE *file, int n){
    //printf("LL function started\n"); //self-explanatory test line
    event_t last;
    head.next = &last;
    int i;
    //This loop will create a ll of the specified length
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        event_t *last = malloc(sizeof(event_t));
        int title_test = fscanf(file, "%20s%*c", last->title);
        printf("%s\n", last->title); //test line to make sure names are grabbed properly
        //This skips the rest of the event and prints error message if title is too long
        if(title_test != 1){
            fscanf(file, "%*s %*d %*d");
            printf("Error: LL event %d title too long\n", i++);
            continue;
        }
        else{
            fscanf(file, "%d %d", &last->date.month, &last->date.day);
            last = last->next;
        }
    }
    printf("Loop exited");
}
```

The test line prints all the titles, but it shows a segmentation fault and aborts before printing "Loop exited"

Comment: When you used your debugger, which line did it say the segfault happened on?

Comment: `head.next = &last;` will end badly, by the way. `head` is a global variable but `last` is a local variable.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica It looks like it's happening right after the loop finishes, is there any way to do a global linked list? It would make it a lot easier to work with since I ultimately need to do more manipulation on this list with several other functions.

Comment: Off by 1. Use  `char title[20];  ....fscanf(file, "%19s%*c", last->title);`/  Post sample input.

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code,

```
event_t *last = malloc(sizeof(event_t));
```

will declare a brand new `last` every time the `for` loops back. Declare it as `static` and adjust your code accordingly, and there should no longer be any problem.

Demo

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    int x=6;
    x++;
    printf("%d ",x);
}
```

Output

```
7 7 7 7 7
```

You should see the problem.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, I need it to loop through to create nodes for every entry in the linked list. The number of entries is a value I get from user input.

Comment: you are trying to do`last=last->next`, however, as you storage class for`last` is `auto`, you didn't achieve what you want; when going to the next round of the `for` loop, you get a brand new `last` instead of `last->next` sorry for my poor English (non native speaker)

Comment: Making `last` `static` will certainly not solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

> The test line prints all the titles, but it shows a segmentation fault and aborts before printing "Loop exited"

There are many bugs in your program. You should read [this post](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You should also learn to use a debugger.

I suspect that the reason `Loop exited` is not printed is that you didn't terminate it with the newline, and so `printf` is waiting for you to complete a line or call `fflush`. By default, `printf` output is *line* buffered. That is one of the reasons you should *always* use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead. `stderr` (by default) is unbuffered.

On to bugs.

1. You have two variables called `last` in the same scope. This is almost never a good idea.
2. This statement:

   `head.next = &last;`

   assigned an address of a *local* variable to a *global* `head` pointer. After the current function returns, that address will become invalid, and this is almost certainly not what you intended. In particular, `head.next` *never* points to any memory you `malloc` (and leak!) in the loop.
3. Your loop looks like this:

   ```
   for (...) {
     event_t *last = malloc(sizeof(event_t));  // last->next is uninitialized
     ...
     last = last->next;  // leak the memory allocated above 
                         // by overwriting the pointer with garbage
   }
   ```

   That is also clearly not what you intended.

Here is one way to build a linked list incrementally:

```
   event_t **link = &head.next;

   for (...) {
     event_t *ev = calloc(...);  // Initializes ev->next to NULL.

     // Fill the rest of ev ...

     // Link it into the list:
     *link = ev;
     link = &ev->next;
   }
```